# Best way to execute math expression string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to execute math expression which is in string like this sample strings:

1. `A = "23>=34"`
2. `B = "77<90"`
3. `C = "33>77"`

and I want some function like `if exec_string(A)` which should return true or false.

Currently I am using this method:

```rb
    rest = --- # I am splitting the string in to three(L- as left number cmpr- as compare and R- as right number )
    class_name.calc(rest[0],rest[1],rest[2])
    def self.calc(L,cmpr,R)
        case cmpr
          when "<"
            if L.to_i < R.to_i
              return true
            end
           ....
           ....
           ....
         end
    end
```

Which could not handle lot of cases. Any help?

Comment: Some users will say that this is bad practice, but you might want to look into [`eval`](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/Eval-Running-Code-On-The-Fly.htm) and [`bindings`](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/Bindings.htm). Perhaps someone with more experience with these functions could comment on whether they're bad practice and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `eval` for that:

```
eval("23>=34")
#=> false
eval("23<=34")
#=> true
```

But keep in mind that `eval` might be evil. Especially if the evaluated string is provided by a user. Imagine what happens if a user enters a command to delete files...

Comment: You should specifically mention that eval runs _any_ ruby code, including those simple expressions, that's why it can be dangerous

Comment: Interesting how this question came up... Similarly, I've been wondering how to solve systems of equations in Ruby. Would a similar `eval` process work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to do this

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified.

```
def self.calc(L, cmpr, R)      
    left = L.to_i
    right = R.to_i
    operator = cmpr.to_sym
    left.send(operator, right)
end
```

For example,

```
irb(main):001:0> 5.send(:+, 7)
=> 12
irb(main):002:0> 3.send(:>=, 5)
=> false
irb(main):003:0> 5.send(:>=, 2)
=> true
irb(main):004:0> 12.send(:-, 3)
=> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try combining `eval` with a regular expression that ensures no letters are present (`/[\d\.\+\s]+/` for example, since my only needed operation is addition).  That way with just numbers and operators, no classes can be instantiated or non-numeric methods invoked.